# JS contactenate numbers from an array instead of adding them

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm doing a JS course on Udemy and I'm stuck with a challenge and the course is really still quite basic so the code I'm writing is basic too.

```
 const bills = [22, 295, 176, 440, 37, 105, 10, 1100, 86, 52];
 let tips = [];
 let totals = [];

 const calcTip = function (bills) {
 return bills >= 50 && bills <= 300 ? bills * 0.15 : bills * 0.2
 }

 // for (i = 0; i < bills.length; i++) {
 //     const newTips = [calcTip(bills[i])];
 //     tips.push(newTips);
 //     const newTotals = [(bills[i] + tips[i])];
 //     totals.push(newTotals);
 // }

 tips = [calcTip(bills[1])];
 totals = [bills[1] + tips[1]];
 console.log(bills, tips, totals);
```

At the minute the totals bit is only for the second item from bills as I wanted to know whether I do it okay, so I'd appreciate a tip why the totals results in NaN in my console. the bills and tips seem to be working fine.
Thank you!

the totals was meant to give me a sum of bill and tip

Comment: Arrays start at 0 in JavaScript.

Comment: when you access `tips[1]` it will return `undefined` because your tips array is empty, so you are adding the result of `bills[1] + undefined` that returns NaN

Comment: Thank you. Now I just need to figure out how to push new totals into the array as the way I'm doing didn't seem to work. I appreciate your help!

Comment: You shouldn't put `[]` around `calcTip(bills[i])` when setting `newTips`. That makes it an array, not a number. And when you use `number + array`, it converts both the number and array to strings and concatenates them.

Comment: You make the same mistake when assigning `newTotals`.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar I figure it out eventually and got the challenge completed in the end.